# How to get SparkUI information Programatically

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to get SparkUI information programatically for spark job?.
I am trying to get all the informations from SparkUI and print in the console when jobs are running. But I didn't find any way to do that.

Is there any way similar to Spark-listener to get all infomation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api? You should be able to get the `app-id` from `sc.applicationId`.